# Is creating and removing lots of branches in git bad?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a main branch `master` that contains the stable code. Each time I want to build something new I `get checkout -b 'development'`, add the new code, then merge it back into the master and delete the development branch.

However, is this creating a larger repo database than just keeping the development branch and merging master into it (so development is up-to-date) before I go to add something new? Do all these temp development branches take extra space in the repo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating temporary branches for single topics/features/tasks is *good*. You're doing it right. Don't just stop with "development" - "featureA", "bugX", "bugX-testing", anything you need, make it!

A branch takes up essentially no space. It's a pointer to the commit at its tip, so it's represented as a file (`.git/refs/heads/branch-name`) whose contents are simply the SHA1 of that commit. Teeny tiny. Eventually they can get gathered up into the `packed-refs` file, which is just a line per branch - name and SHA1, even smaller than the original!  (Git does this to avoid having too many *files* in a repo which has, say, 1000 minor/maintenance release version tags in its history.) They do also have reflogs, which record a line each time the position of the branch changes (try `git reflog show` to see the reflog for HEAD), but again, that's pretty small - and it's removed when you remove the branch.

Answer (score 4):

As Jefromi explained, branches are designed to be ridiculously cheap. Not only that, as far as I know, Git is [the only major, free VCS](http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/) that does branching this way.

Given how you seem to be using branches, I think you'd benefit from nvie's GitFlow [branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and [helper extension](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/) (link to explanatory blog post) as a simple, clean way to make the most of branching for release management. (Basically, a more polished approach to what you seem to already be doing)

Answer (score 1):

It is not bad and actually recommended for experimental code.

If you are worried about your repo size, use 'git gc' to collect garbage and compress it.